# joomla 2.5 system uploader variable

Tags: php, joomla

Using the joomla 2.5 uploader var

and this code does not work somewhere in here is a error and my debugger does not catch it
was wondering if someone else has a joomla debugg form that will address this and fix the problem..

```
function fileUpload($max, $module_dir, $file_type, $msg){
        //Retrieve file details from uploaded file, sent from upload form
        $file = JRequest::getVar('image', null, 'files', 'array');
        if(isset($file)){ 
                //Clean up filename to get rid of strange characters like spaces etc
                $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);

                if($file['size'] > $max) $msg = JText::_('ONLY_FILES_UNDER').' '.$max;
                //Set up the source and destination of the file

                $src = $file['tmp_name'];
                $dest = $module_dir . DS .$filename;

                //First check if the file has the right extension, we need jpg only
                if ($file['type'] == $file_type | | $file_type == '*') { 
                   if ( JFile::upload($src, $dest) ) {

                       //Redirect to a page of your choice
                        $msg = JText::_('FILE_SAVE_AS').' '.$dest;
                   } else {
                          //Redirect and throw an error message
                        $msg = JText::_('ERROR_IN_UPLOAD');
                    }
                } else {
                   //Redirect and notify user file is not right extension
                        $msg = JText::_('FILE_TYPE_INVALID');
                }

                $msg = "<script>alert('". $msg ."');</script>";
        }
        return $msg;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to print the contents of $file var, if not can you please tell us what is the output you get when you execute print_r($file);

Comment: used print_r($file); command and all i get is a blank page no debug is available so apparently it is stopping on one of the lines of code and breaking the site from loading

Comment: IS the error reporting on? What is the error you get?

Comment: make sure you set error reporting in the Joomla Global Configuration to **development** so you can see what is happening

Comment: i have the debugger set on but it does not report anything cause the page never loads at all and if i take out the above code then it loads just fine so something is wrong in this code but i can not debug it

Comment: You need error reporting on, not the debugger. Where are you adding this code to?

Comment: write now i have it loaded in a file called upload.php tring to incorporate it into a module i have been writing and yes i know error reporting in the global config and language reporting is on... if i tell the script to call upload.php it breaks the site completely and will not load anything i just get a blank page no error codes nothing

Comment: Please stick to the Joomla methods. Add this code to your *helper.php* file which should be called from *mod_my_module.php* and wrap it in a function. If you remember, I have already told you twice that the helper.php file is used to store all the functions which process information therefore you should use it.

Comment: It still sounds like you are mixing up turning on the debugger, on the system screen, with error reporting, on the server screen.   You are also not being nearly careful enough about user input, file uploads are one of the most dangerous things possible, you should use the core media helper to make sure you are doing all relevant checks. Also you are using a ton of deprecated things (DS, JRequest) which you are going to regret later.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in \modules\mod_kos\helper.php on line 52 which is the else commands in this file